# Windows cannot open "Network And Sharing Center"

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

I cannot open "Network And Sharing Center" on my Windows 8.1 computer. When I try to get access to this window/dialog nothing happens. 
I usually right click on the network icon in the taskbar, and select "Network And Sharing Center". This takes about 5-10 minutes (!) to load, and when loaded, I cannot get access to any of the settings in that window.

I tried booting the computer in failsafe mode, but the problem still existed.

I want to hear if anybody has had the same experience, if not, I will try to restore Windows, and hope that it helps.

Comment: Try running `sfc /scannow` to check the integrity of system files -> reboot once the scan has completed -> Check to see if problem resolved -> run malware/anti-virus scan -> reboot -> try again... short of backing up and restoring these are a few steps to consider

Comment: There is some useful stuff at http://www.tweaking.com/content/overview/default.html which I've found great for the non-expert. The all-in-one would be my go-to, but +1 for your first steps @BigChris